# Firebase Storage Error From Firebase Website

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-console

Has anyone encountered this error? It is not giving a description from console.firebase.google.com. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is likely that you've run out of quota in our free plan. The console will be affected by this, unfortunately :(

You can verify this by performing any request (or looking in the developer console) and seeing a `402` which means you've exceeded your quota. Just upgrade your plan to a paid plan or wait until the quota refreshes (midnight PST).

We're working on a better error message here, since it's obviously not a great experience to see nothing.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I had thought that might have something to do with it.